# Spring Data Rest request with specific results

Tags: mysql, angularjs, request, spring-data, httprequest

I'm using Spring Data REST and Angular to build a website, which is connected to my mySQL-DB.

With a http-request like this I'll get my data:

```
$scope.getAllHolidays = function(){
        var URL = String('http://localhost:8080/holidays?projection=noHolidayweek');
        $http({
            url: URL,
            method: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        })
        .then(useData);
    };
```

Now it will bring me all holidays with their informations (included data joined by a foreign key).
My result looks like:

```
  "_embedded" : {
"holidays" : [ {
  "strTitle" : "Summer 2016",
  "byteHolidayReason" : 0,
  "bolEnabled" : false,
  "holidayweek" : [ {
    "shortYear" : 2016,
    "byteWeek" : 29,
    "occupancy" : [ { <-- joined table
      "intNumber" : 0,
    }, {
      "intNumber" : 3,
    }, {
      "intNumber" : 2,
{ AND SO ON (LARGE ARRAY) }]
  }]
```

But my problem is, that I only want to get specific informations without the data from the join, because it includes much data and is useless at this point.

**UPDATE:**
I added my Model and Controller and created a Projection to my Repository like @Valerio Vaudi proposed me, but it still doesn't works.

My model (main.holiday.model):

```
@Entity
public class Holiday {

public Holiday(){

}

@Id
@Column(name="holiday_id")
private Long LongHoliday_id = main.modules.calcID.calculateID();

@Column(name="Title")
private String strTitle;

@Column(name="HolidayReason")
private byte byteHolidayReason;
//0=Sommer
//1=Winter

@Column(name="Enabled")
private boolean bolEnabled;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "holiday_id")
private Set<Holidayweek> holidayweeks = new HashSet<Holidayweek>();


//setter & getter
```

My Repository (main.holiday.controller):

```
public interface HolidayRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Holiday, Long>,
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Holiday> {

}

@Projection(name = "noHolidayweek", types = {Holiday.class})
interface NoHolidayweek{
    Long getLongHoliday_id();
    String getStrTitle();
    Byte getByteHolidayReason();
    Boolean getBolEnabled();
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Pass query parameters in URL and filter result in backend

Comment: Ok, and how can I do this?

Comment: Did you mean to make a normal request and then filtering the non relevant data?

Comment: no. You can pass query string in your URL: like,http://localhost:8080/holidays?getOnly=id

Comment: You can pass whatever you want to filter in Backend.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your answer. But I already do so. And I'll only get my needed data. But this data contains a large array of an joined table which is useless at the actual template so my goal is it to filter an request without getting this obsolete data to reduce the load-process.

Comment: I added a result in my explanation, maybe it teaches better what my problem is.

Comment: See. It has nothing to do with angular. This can be achieved by sql query.

Comment: rewrite the sql query to fetch data from single table . otherwise post  SQL query , I will correct it

Comment: I didn't wrote an own query, With the URL in my http-request the framework provides me the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want reduce the information amount you can consider the projection technique, I can suggest to read the doc about this topic [Projection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections).

consider a model like bolow:

```
 @Entity
    public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String street;
    private String city;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Address> addressList;
      …
    }
```

suppose that it had too mutch info and you want less info you can do like bolow:

declare an interface like below

```
    @Projection(name = "personProjectionCriteria", types = Person.class)
public interface PersonProjectionCriteria {

    String getFirstName();

    String getLastName();
}

@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = PersonProjectionCriteria.class)
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

}
```

then use it in you url like below

http://localhost:8080/person**?projection=personProjectionCriteria**.

**Update**
an important think is that the interface marked as @Projection must located in the same package (or sub-package) of the domain type.

I posted some screen for document how I want say.
[[image: all resource][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOdyV.png)]

[image: projected]

[image: code]

If this approach isn't enough yon should consider of build the your own rest api with a classical Spring MVC or JAx-RS approach and perform a fine grained tuning.

I hope that it can help you

**Update** 
After the your post of code i try to fix the bugs and in the my githHub at link [code](https://github.com/mrFlick72/hateoas-holiday) you can find the solution. In the forked repo you can see many changed because in your code at the time of fork 05/08/2016, I found many errors in the layout of code and in the code itself. In an ordedly fashion in the code posted the your bug don't exist in fact of you define an entity with dependency but after you define a repository interfaces for this entities. Spring data rest in this case will replace the embedded dependency with a link. Indeed if you don't define an repository interface like below Spring data rest will insert the embedded entity relation and you get the problem described in your question.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface HolidayweekRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Holidayweek, Long> {

}
```

The only way for overcame it is define a projection and apply it as i describe above in my answares. in your code i find the projection in the controller pakage and not in the model pakage and for tihs reason you cont benefit of projection.

In the link of forked repo I corrected the code in a way that yon don't get the data on relation but you get the link if you don't want it and you want benefit of usage of projection you have delete the repository interface of relation entity and define the projection interface under the model pakage and not controller pakage and intert excerptProjection = NoHolidayweek.class if you want that the projection will be applyed by default in /holidays url or don't insert it on @RepositoryRestResource if you don't want this behaviour.

I hope that it now is clear.

Comment: Hello, I just edited my Repository like in your example and changed my request to "http://localhost:8080/holidays?projection=noHolidayweek", but the request gives me the same data as before.

Comment: I had update the my answare and I hope that it can help you to understand the my hints

Comment: I updated my question, too. Like you see, my controller(repo) and model are located in the same package, but it doesn't works.

Comment: it is very strange because i try it in a small poc and in my implementation works. However I see that in your jquery ajax call you put http://localhost:8080/holidays/ and not http://localhost:8080/holidays?projection=noHolidayweek

Comment: I use Spring boot for this poc but it is not fundamental think Spring data rest woks in the same way in a boot or bootless enviroment

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the part above too, but now it's right. But in my project, the query was already adjusted to yours, but without reaching my goal...

Comment: one think that i note different respect to my example, is the presence of QueryDslPredicateExecutor. now I'dont't have experience on this kind of interface, but can I suggest of leavse this and try?.

Comment: I update the answer in which I underline the interface that I use as endpoint

Comment: in this link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/projections there is a sample developed by Spring team itself

Comment: At first I'm very grateful for all your answers, but I tried all. Changing my Repository to yours, setting an excerpt like in your github-example. But nothing works. I think, there must be another problem we can't find out.

Comment: if yon can post the code on github I can to try to fix the problem, because for projection the recipes is as I write. Probably you have another think in your code that broke the process and if I can read and test your code probably I can find the problem and fix it.

Comment: I've never worked with github before, so I hope that's enough for you: https://github.com/phil1205/hateoas-holiday . In the uploaded project I disabled the projection, so feel free ;).Thank you for your help!

Comment: I update the answare an post the corrected code on my github https://github.com/mrFlick72

Comment: Yes great, it works! But two Questions still: You changed the way I set up the relations. Now it adds me extra tables to declare the relation between the tables, instead of joining a foreign key in the original table. Is this better for me or not? The second question is, that if I'll make a request for e.g. holidays, it always doesn't shows me holidayweeks and occupancy, which is only required, if I give a projection.

Comment: I noticed, that the problem results because of the extra tables so they aren't directly connected anymore, which leads to the less data. But this wasn't my goal.

Comment: So now, I changed my relations to my old example and it joins the foreign key successful. Furthermore the projection works and my goal is reached! Thank you very much for your help and maybe you can explain me, why you wrote the relation like in your example, because I wanna understand it.

Comment: I wrote the relation in the way that you see in my version of your project because in the unversity of Rome La Sapienza the my prof teach of implements the relation in this way. The benefit in DBA prospective was that in this way you have less depencency in your entity of the relation. In your case you have a join column in my case a join table. It is only a stilistic  fashion, but I prefeare the my way of wrote relation but it is a my habit.

Comment: Say, do you know how to post in these tables with relation, e.g. 1:n? I started a next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843733/spring-data-rest-post-tables-with-relation and need professional help ^^

Comment: I'm sorry but I work in a Software company and I can't give you professional support

Comment: So you don't know how to do?

Comment: I would say that I can help you respect question on StackOverflow because in this place I don't violate the contract that I had with my company, but I cant give you commercial support

Comment: Well, did you mean because of getting knowledge by your company?

Comment: I'm working with openseurce product like Liferay and Alfresco

Comment: for your other question as soon as possible I answare

Comment: And now, I have a new question: Is it possible to use projection in a query about more tables?